# How to compress transaction's input?

Tags: solidity, transactions, abi, decoding

Any idea to compress the input data to erase the much zeros

From: `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`

To: `0x8f2b7a67a19a81a38bf2238a695629fa7b4a909a2390ddb4052fea3caafaaf3f95ec536b30714bff78dbac5b01e1400013247aacf6002d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf127c17b109e146934d36c33e55fade9cbda791b036602c17b109e146934d36c33e55fade9cbda791b0366d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270`

Comment: Is there any reason u want to erase the padding zeros ?  the input data is designed to encode with padding 0 for 32 bytes.

Comment: I want to compressed the input to save the gas

Comment: in your code you should use `abi.encodePacked(var1,var2,etc.)`

Comment: Thank you @AdamBoudjemaa
could you please tell me any example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use abi.encodePacked, here is a quick example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Demo {
     
    function encode(uint8 a, uint16 b, bool c, string calldata d) external pure returns(bytes memory) {
      return abi.encode(a,b,c,d);
    }

        function encodePacked(uint8 a, uint16 b, bool c, string calldata d) external pure returns(bytes memory) {
      return abi.encodePacked(a,b,c,d);
    }
}
```

`encode` function returns `bytes: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

while encodePacked returns `bytes: 0x0100010131`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate this.

now how can I back from 0x0100010131 to a,b,c,d, to put them in another function

Answer (score 0):

### Calldata

when submitting a transaction, the calldata is structured like so: the first 4 bytes contain the function signature and for each function argument you get 32 bytes padded with zeroes. In your example:

```
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
```

`0x8f2b7a67` is the function signature and it's followed by 13 arguments (each struct key or array element counts as an argument)

`000000000000000000000000a19a81a38bf2238a695629fa7b4a909a2390ddb4` (probably an address)

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (0)

`000000000000000000000000052fea3caafaaf3f95ec536b30714bff78dbac5b` (looks like an address)

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` (1)

`00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0` (224)

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140` (320)

`00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013247aacf6000000` (1379362269162373120)

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002` (2)

`0000000000000000000000000d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270` (another address)

`000000000000000000000000c17b109e146934d36c33e55fade9cbda791b0366` (address again)

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002` (2)

`000000000000000000000000c17b109e146934d36c33e55fade9cbda791b0366` (same address)

`0000000000000000000000000d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270` (and an address again)

Calldata in solidity is pretty cheap: 4 gas per `0x00` byte and 16 gas per byte with a non-zero value.

### Tight-Packing

You could tight-pack these arguments together (see [Tight Packing](https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/tight_variable_packing.html)) but you would have to

- Find smaller types for each argument that will be consistent with their maximum value. For example for your argument #4 (1) maybe it's a `uint8` (max 255), or a `uint16` (max 65535), ...
- Change your method so that it accepts packed `uint256` or `bytes32` variables
- Extract each variable through bitwise operations

It's very likely that doing this will result in a higher gas cost.

If you post your function params and the code you use to call that function, I can propose some code implementing this solution